# yii extension egmap geocode on text change

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/egmap/ to implement google map.
the issue is I've a address field. if user type an address the I want my marker to pan to new position. How is this possible using this extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2011/02/05/a-reverse-geolocator-tool-with-egmap-2-0-extension/ (blog of the author of egmap)

Or have a look at `EGMapGeocodedAddress`and specially the method `reverseGeocode`